# Sqlfluff: Cannot instantiate a templated file unsliced

Tags: dbt, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit.com, sqlfluff

I recently decided to add sqlfluff to my dbt project so i just followed https://docs.sqlfluff.com/en/stable/production.html and added sqlfluff with pre-commit to my project.

Following is how my very basic .sqlfluff configurations look like:

```
[sqlfluff]
dialect = postgres
templater = jinja
output_line_length = 80
ignore_templated_areas = True
runaway_limit = 100


[sqlfluff:rules]
tab_space_size = 2
max_line_length = 120
indent_unit = space
comma_style = trailing

[sqlfluff:rules:L014]
extended_capitalisation_policy = lower

[sqlfluff:templater:jinja]
apply_dbt_builtins = true
```

Here is  .pre-commit-config.yaml:

```
repos:
      - repo: https://github.com/sqlfluff/sqlfluff
        rev: 1.0.0
        hooks:
          - id: sqlfluff-lint
            name: sqlfluff-lint
            entry: sqlfluff lint
            language: python
            description: 'Lints sql files with `SQLFluff`'
            types: [sql]
            require_serial: true
            additional_dependencies: []
    
          - id: sqlfluff-fix
            name: sqlfluff-fix
            # Needs to use "--force" to disable confirmation
            # By default all the rules are applied
            entry: sqlfluff fix --force
            language: python
            description: 'Fixes sql lint errors with `SQLFluff`'
            types: [sql]
            require_serial: true
            additional_dependencies: []
```

Once I run pre-commit run --all-files I end up getting the following:

````
  File "/root/.cache/pre-commit/repo20y2aa42/py_env-python3.8/bin/sqlfluff", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
  File "/root/.cache/pre-commit/repo20y2aa42/py_env-python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1130, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/.cache/pre-commit/repo20y2aa42/py_env-python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1055, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/root/.cache/pre-commit/repo20y2aa42/py_env-python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1657, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/root/.cache/pre-commit/repo20y2aa42/py_env-python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1404, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/root/.cache/pre-commit/repo20y2aa42/py_env-python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 760, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/.cache/pre-commit/repo20y2aa42/py_env-python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlfluff/cli/commands.py", line 769, in fix
    result = lnt.lint_paths(
  File "/root/.cache/pre-commit/repo20y2aa42/py_env-python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlfluff/core/linter/linter.py", line 1143, in lint_paths
    self.lint_path(
  File "/root/.cache/pre-commit/repo20y2aa42/py_env-python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlfluff/core/linter/linter.py", line 1095, in lint_path
    for i, linted_file in enumerate(runner.run(fnames, fix), start=1):
  File "/root/.cache/pre-commit/repo20y2aa42/py_env-python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlfluff/core/linter/runner.py", line 101, in run
    for fname, partial in self.iter_partials(fnames, fix=fix):
  File "/root/.cache/pre-commit/repo20y2aa42/py_env-python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlfluff/core/linter/runner.py", line 54, in iter_partials
    for fname, rendered in self.iter_rendered(fnames):
  File "/root/.cache/pre-commit/repo20y2aa42/py_env-python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlfluff/core/linter/runner.py", line 43, in iter_rendered
    yield fname, self.linter.render_file(fname, self.config)
  File "/root/.cache/pre-commit/repo20y2aa42/py_env-python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlfluff/core/linter/linter.py", line 816, in render_file
    return self.render_string(raw_file, fname, config, encoding)
  File "/root/.cache/pre-commit/repo20y2aa42/py_env-python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlfluff/core/linter/linter.py", line 787, in render_string
    templated_file, templater_violations = self.templater.process(
  File "/root/.cache/pre-commit/repo20y2aa42/py_env-python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlfluff/core/templaters/jinja.py", line 413, in process
    TemplatedFile(
  File "/root/.cache/pre-commit/repo20y2aa42/py_env-python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlfluff/core/templaters/base.py", line 102, in __init__
    raise ValueError("Cannot instantiate a templated file unsliced!")
ValueError: Cannot instantiate a templated file unsliced!```

Not sure what breaking this
````

Answer (score 1):

so first off your configuration has a bunch of unnecessary things in it -- let's pare that down (you also don't need both `-lint` and `-fix` -- they're redundant):

```yaml
repos:
      - repo: https://github.com/sqlfluff/sqlfluff
        rev: 1.0.0
        hooks:
          - id: sqlfluff-fix
```

and with that configuration I can't reproduce your error -- you'll need to provide a sql file which triggers the particular error I suspect and your associated templates

---

disclaimer: I created pre-commit

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and making sure to exclude folders (macros and dbt_packages) having templated files solved this issue for me.

https://docs.sqlfluff.com/en/stable/configuration.html

Print screen of default .sqlfluffignore file on official site:
[.sqlfluffignore default file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxM4p.png)

I hope this helps!